# How do I prevent CKEditor 4 from stripping Google AdSense asynchronous tags?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, input-formats

For whatever reason, CKEditor 4 is stripping Google AdSense asynchronous tags from my Full HTML text format.

What starts as this (placeholders substituted for IDs):

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
</script>
<!-- Top Banner -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXX"
    data-ad-slot="XXXXX"></ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Ends up as this:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
</script>
<!-- Top Banner -->
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Again, this is in the Full HTML text format and I'm able to get the *ins* tag through without attributes, but not with attributes, even though other tags have no problems getting their attributes through to save.

For what it's worth, I do have the following set on the CKEditor profile:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

**UPDATE**

CKEditor is only stripping the *ins* tag (and attributes) when it's an empty tag as given by AdSense. If I add anything – a non-breaking space, even – CKEditor is preserving the *ins* tag and attributes.

Per tenken's suggestion, I added the following line to my config, but it didn't help.

```
config.protectedSource.push( /<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\" style=\".*\" data-ad-client=\".*\" data-ad-slot=\".*\"\><\/ins\>/g );
```

Comment: Are you sure this behavior does not happen with just a filter format of `FULL_HTML` and no WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Good question. The snippet is getting through using a textarea without CKEditor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read this blogpost (not by me) [Drupal WYSYWG Module Custom CkEditor Configuration](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/drupal-wysiwyg-module-custom-ckeditor-configuration-725.html) by Philip Norton.

Your `<script>` tags are not being stripped out, but the funky `<ins>` tag is. From that blog post you should be able to add a `protectedSource` to the AFC rules so that those elements are not stripped. This is untested but deriving from the blogpost:

```
// Allow Google Adsense <ins> tags, I'm being more specific
// than allowing any raw <ins> tag here. This may be too specific, but
// play with it.
config.protectedSource.push( /<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"\>.*?<\/ins\>/g );
```

In order for this configuration to work you may have to install the [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module (or append to your own ckeditor javascript profile directly).

Comment: Great read. Thank you for sharing. After further testing, it appears CKEditor is stripping out the ins tag because it's empty. It will allow the ins tag – attributes and all – if I put something, anything in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is from: http://margotskapacs.com/2014/08/taking-ckeditor-a-apart/

There is defined list of tags that is going to be removed if empty(see dtd.js and $removeEmpty). To ensure the certain empty tag are not being removed, add attribute ‘data-cke-survive’:

or pass the following to the CKEditor configuration file:

CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = 0;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['TAG-NAME'] = 0;

This make the empty tags to not being removed
NOTE: If you working with the production CKEditor.js, you will have to alter section starting “CKEDITOR.dtd” as following:

CKEDITOR.dtd=function(){var a=CKEDITOR.tools.extend,e=function(a,d){for(var [...]
span:0//set the 
TAG:0
..
You will have to grep the CKEditor.js file for section starting “CKEDITOR.dtd” and then change value from 1 to 0 for each tags you like to not be removed if empty(see above example for ‘span’ tag)